# DKIM: fail (body hash did not verify) but DMARC: pass

Tags: dkim, dmarc

I received an email (using Office365) which had the following:

```
spf=pass 
dkim=fail (body hash did not verify)
dmarc=pass action=none
compauth=pass reason=100
```

Should DMARC not fail when DKIM fails or?

Part of mail header (redacted):

```
Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is 185.XXX.XXX.XXX)
 smtp.mailfrom=xxxxx.com; yyyyy.com; dkim=fail (body hash did not verify)
 header.d=xxxxx.com;yyyyy.com; dmarc=pass action=none
 header.from=xxxxx.com;compauth=pass reason=100
Received-SPF: Pass (protection.outlook.com: domain of xxxxx.com designates
 185.XXX.XXX.XXX as permitted sender) receiver=protection.outlook.com;
 client-ip=185.XXX.XXX.XXX; helo=xxxxx.com;
Received: xxxxx.com (185.XXX.XXX.XXX) by
 XXXXT057.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.152.5.104) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id
 15.20.3370.16 via Frontend Transport; Tue, 15 Sep 2020 09:28:04 +0000
Received: from [10.244.53.49] (unknown [62.xxx.xxx.xxx])
    (Authenticated sender: johndoe@xxxxx.com)
    by xxxxx.com (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 958xxxxxx
    for <janedoe@yyyyy.com>; Tue, 15 Sep 2020 09:27:59 +0000 (UTC)
DKIM-Filter: OpenDKIM Filter v2.11.0 xxxxx.com 95811831E7
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=xxxxx.com;
    s=default; t=1600162079;
    bh=nuM3cWrinDLZjraJCy30WYG0ePetEpsDwkYbe7tHCOs=;
    h=Date:Subject:From:To:From;
    b=jJZ91ejcq4Tu3xV+PtcT1/pgwHbUXQRxFLbilFKFiYTnBi1Zn31vzAHbPe4o40HM0
     gi+7F9TdBu47MhNwTFIvY94M+uSx1U4B9Ci9hTSDwEaDGazONyB8ER1fFmD7LPRMvV
     oXdTEACywQrrYPPb15RkSUNg6m8+6AJjdMgDrRDU=
```

Comment: Share header details to examine the problem.

Answer (score 1):

### **Short answer:**

No, DMARC fails *if and only if*:

1. SPF *or* SPF Alignment has failed, **and**
2. DKIM *or* DKIM Alignment has failed

If only one of them fails and the other passes, DMARC will pass.

### Some more details around DMARC failures and the protocol in general:

An important detail to keep in mind from the perspective of DMARC is that a failure for SPF or DKIM can mean 2 things:

1. The underlying SPF or DKIM ***authentication*** has failed, or
2. The underlying SPF or DKIM ***alignment*** has failed.

**Authentication** is probably clear since it is related to the underlying protocols themselves.

**Alignment** is an additional feature introduced by DMARC, which checks if the domains used for the SPF/DKIM authentication are in alignment with the domain portion of the RFC5322.From domain (which is the domain portion of the sender's email address, e.g. senderxyz@`domain.com`). 
A successful SPF/DKIM alignment implies that the domains are either identical or that the SPF/DKIM domain is a subdomain of the RFC5321.From domain. This is called a *strict* or *relaxed* alignment respectively, and can be controlled via the `aspf` and `adkim` tags in your DMARC Record.